# How samples should be included in principal component analysis

Tags: pca

I intend to use PCA to identify the sources of contaminants in environmental samples. We have data from both environmental samples and suspected sources. We want to use PCA to check which sources have a chemical composition that is similar to the environmental samples, therefore, could be the primary sources. The similarity in the composition is depicted using the score plot.  I can do the PCA in two ways: the first method is to include the data from both samples and sources, and run a PCA. The second method is to include only the sample data in the PCA, and use the PCA model to predict the scores for the sources.  I do not know Which method is correct? or there are some limitations or restrictions for both methods, and the selection of the method is dependent on the dataset.

Comment: Could be better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/